# simple drools rules fail optimization in optaplanner

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I'm having a (for new) pretty easy optimization issue: a full (academic) programme consists of several modules. Each module has a weight and can be given in a certain half of the year (first or second). We want to optimize the 'trajectories' for a student (so, a student may already have passed some courses or so). What I'm doing right now is: a full year needs to have at least a weight of 27, a semester can't have more than a weight of 30. This is what I added as rules:

```
rule "max weight per semester (per academic year)"
    when
        Module( $semester : semester, $year : year )
        $semesterWeight : Number(intValue > 30) from accumulate(
            Module(semester == $semester, year == $year, $weight : weight), sum($weight))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 30 - $semesterWeight.intValue());
end

rule "min weight per academic year"
    when
        Module( $year : year )
        $semesterWeight : Number(intValue <= 27) from accumulate(
            Module(year == $year, $weight : weight), sum($weight))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, (27 - $semesterWeight.intValue()) * 6 );
end
```

So, if read them like this:

1. for each module with semester `$semester` and year `$year`, optimize so that the sum of all modules in that `$year` and `$semester` is at least 30
2. for each module in year `$year`, optimize so that the sum of all the weights of the modules in that year is at least 27.

However, optaplanner seems to fail to optimize this. The result, with only a few modules in there (I'm just trying out optaplanner):

```
648hard/0medium/0soft
1-AcademicYear(start=2020): [6/SdI/1]
1-AcademicYear(start=2014): [3/BUI./1]
1-AcademicYear(start=2019): [6/.PS/1]
2-AcademicYear(start=2017): [6/COMP.FIG/1]
1-AcademicYear(start=2013): [6/INFOSYSI/1]
```

So, it puts all modules i a separate acadeic year. I don't understand why optaplanner is doing this, because it seems somewhat counterintuitive to me. As far as I understand, optaplanner does a first fit, which should already put the modules in the same year. But it isn't. I didn't put any optimization configs in my config:

```
<solver>
    <scanAnnotatedClasses/>

    <scoreDirectorFactory>
        <scoreDrl>pdtScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>
    </scoreDirectorFactory>

    <termination>
        <secondsSpentLimit>10</secondsSpentLimit>
    </termination>
</solver>
```

Am I doing the rules wrong, or am I missing something else?
(It looks like Optaplanner is not trying different academic years.)

Answer (score 1):

Simple drools rules, but I should them write right:

```
rule "min weight per academic year"
    when
        Module( $year : year )
        $semesterWeight : Number(intValue <= 27) from accumulate(
            Module(year == $year, $weight : weight), sum($weight))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, (27 - $semesterWeight.intValue()) * 6 );
end
```

Instead of having a negative number for the hard constraint, it is possitive. I had to reverse the terms in `27 - $semesterWeight.intValue()`.

Comment: Yea, that's a common pitfall. ConstraintStreams avoids that pitfall: `from(Module.class).groupBy(Module::getYear, sum(Module::getWeight)).filter((module, weight) -> weight <= 27).penalize("min weigh per year", ofHard(6), (module, weight) -> 27 - weight));` So the penalize method only accepts a positive number, even though it ends up negative in the score.